# dropdownlist postback in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The scenario is I have got 2 dropdown list and a table in which i am displaying my data.

The requirement is second dropdown is filled depending upon the first dropdown and the table data is also reloaded.so how can i post my page and reload entire data in MVC3.

I wanted to post my page onchange of first dropdown and second dropdown also.

I have tried using the following in view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("SectorDropDown",
        (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["SectorDropDown"], 
        new { onchange = "this.form.action='/Screener/Screener.aspx';this.form.submit;"           }
) %>
```

Komal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you posting back to a different Action to the Submit button? If not, you don't need to specify the action in the onchange handler. Your submit is missing the parentheses and should be:

```
 this.form.submit();
```

Comment: I was missing the parenthesis part so the page couldnt be posted.

Comment: Could you mark the question answered then? Thanks